# JMeter : Regex extracting from an array response

Tags: regex, api, jmeter

I want to extract the **addressId** for a given housenumber in a response with a long array. The array response looks like this (snippet):

```
:   :   "footprint":null,
:   :   "type":null,
:   :   "addressId":"0011442239",
:   :   "streetName":"solitudestr.",
:   :   "streetNrFirstSuffix":null,
:   :   "streetNrFirst":null,
:   :   "streetNrLastSuffix":null,
:   :   "streetNrLast":null,
:   :   "houseNumber":"25",
:   :   "houseName":null,
:   :   "city":"stuttgart",
:   :   "postcode":"70499",
:   :   "stateOrProvince":null,
:   :   "countryName":null,
:   :   "poBoxNr":null,
:   :   "poBoxType":null,
:   :   "attention":null,
:   :   "geographicAreas":
:   :   [
:   :   ],
:   :   "firstName":null,
:   :   "lastName":null,
:   :   "title":null,
:   :   "region":"BW",
:   :   "additionalInfo":null,
:   :   "properties":
:   :   [
:   :   ],
:   :   "extAddressId":null,
:   :   "entrance":null,
:   :   "district":null,
:   :   "addressLine1":null,
:   :   "addressLine2":null,
:   :   "addressLine3":null,
:   :   "addressLine4":null,
:   :   "companyName":null,
:   :   "contactName":null,
:   :   "houseNrExt":null,
:   :   "derbyStack":false
:   },
:   {
:   :   "footprint":null,
:   :   "type":null,
:   :   "addressId":"0011442246",
:   :   "streetName":"solitudestr.",
:   :   "streetNrFirstSuffix":null,
:   :   "streetNrFirst":null,
:   :   "streetNrLastSuffix":null,
:   :   "streetNrLast":null,
:   :   "houseNumber":"26",
:   :   "houseName":null,
:   :   "city":"stuttgart",
:   :   "postcode":"70499",
:   :   "stateOrProvince":null,
:   :   "countryName":null,
:   :   "poBoxNr":null,
:   :   "poBoxType":null,
:   :   "attention":null,
:   :   "geographicAreas":
:   :   [
:   :   ],
:   :   "firstName":null,
:   :   "lastName":null,
:   :   "title":null,
:   :   "region":"BW",
:   :   "additionalInfo":null,
:   :   "properties":
:   :   [
:   :   ],
:   :   "extAddressId":null,
:   :   "entrance":null,
:   :   "district":null,
:   :   "addressLine1":null,
:   :   "addressLine2":null,
:   :   "addressLine3":null,
:   :   "addressLine4":null,
:   :   "companyName":null,
:   :   "contactName":null,
:   :   "houseNrExt":null,
:   :   "derbyStack":false
:   },
```

i only show 2 housenumbers in this response as an example but the original response is bigger.

Q: How can i match the **adressId** for a specific houseNumber (i have these houseNumbers in my CSV dataset) ? I Could do a regex which extracts all addressId's but then i'd have to use the correct matching no. in Jmeter. However, i cannot assume that the ordening of these will remain same in the different environments we test the script against.

Comment: Like this [`"addressId":"(\d+)"(?=(?:(?!\n: +: +\[)[\s\S])*houseNumber":"26|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/kL9xQ8/1)?

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: Did it work in JMeter, too? Just occurred to me that the lookahead is redundant.

Comment: In jmeter i got :  2016/08/12 13:01:34 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher.__match(Unknown Source)

Comment: Ok, a better one: [`"addressId":"(\d+)"(?:.*(?:\n(?!: +: +\[).*)*houseNumber":"25"|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/kL9xQ8/2). Or even more reliable: [`"addressId":"(\d+)"(?:[^\n"]*(?:\n(?!: +: +\[)[^\n"]*|"(?!houseNumber")[^\n"]*)*"houseNumber":"25"|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/kL9xQ8/3). Sorry, they are not maintainable... You just have to understand how unroll-the-loop principle works to be able to modify them.

Comment: i replaced the number 25 with my houseno. variable from csv data, works perfectly. thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend reconsidering using regular expressions to deal with JSON data.

Starting from JMeter 3.0 you have a [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor). Using it you can execute arbitrary [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) queries so extracting the `addressID` for the given `houseNumber` would be as simple as:

```
`$..[?(@.houseNumber == '25')].addressId`
```

Demo:

[image: JSON Path Demo]

You can use a JMeter Variable instead of the hard-coded `25` value like:

```
$..[?(@.houseNumber == '${houseNumber}')].addressId
```

---

If for some reason you have to use JMeter < 3.0 you still can have JSON Path postprocessing capabilities using [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

See [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) article, in particular **Conditional Select** chapter for more information.

Comment: If [one of your answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2897748+%5Bjmeter%5D+JSON) is next to identical, maybe you should close the question as a dupe?

Answer (score 2):

You may use a regex that will capture the digits after `addressId` and before a specific `houseNumber` if you use an *unrolled tempered greedy token* (for better efficiency) in between them to make sure the regex engine does not overflow to another record.

```
"addressId":"(\d+)"(?:[^\n"]*(?:\n(?!: +: +\[)[^\n"]*|"(?!houseNumber")[^\n"]*)*"houseNumber":"25"|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL9xQ8/3) (replace `25` with the necessary house number)

**Details**:

- `"addressId":"` - literal string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`$1$` template value) capturing 1+ digits
- `"` - a quote
- `(?:[^\n"]*(?:\n(?!: +: +\[)[^\n"]*|"(?!houseNumber")[^\n"]*)*"houseNumber":"25"|$)` - a non-capturing group with 2 alternatives, one being `$` (end of string) or:

  - `[^\n"]*` - zero or more chars other than newline and `"`
  - `(?:` - then come 2 alternatives:

    - `\n(?!: +: +\[)[^\n"]*` - a newline not followed with `: : [` like string and followed with 0+chars other than a newline and `"`
    - `|` - or
    - `"(?!houseNumber")[^\n"]*` - a `"` not followed with `houseNumber` and followed with 0+chars other than a newline and `"`
  - `)*` - than may repeat 0 or more times
- `"houseNumber":"25"` - hourse number literal string.