# JMeter how to extract ids from array of items from response using regular expression extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am new to JMeter completely. I have similar issue related to [JMeter : Regex extracting from an array response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916244/jmeter-regex-extracting-from-an-array-response)
Here i am using the same test payload. I am trying to use Regular Expression Extractor and would like to extract all addressIds. ie [0011442239, 0011442246]. I have a post request to be sent and the payload is only the array of addressIds. Can anyone please help me with this?

I tried to use `\[([^\]]+)\`] but this didnt worked. As I mentioned above i am completely new to JMeter and Regular Expressin.

sorry my mistake i am expecting the response as integer arrays. i.e [0011442239, 0011442246].

Thanks

```
[
  {
    "footprint": null,
    "type": null,
    "addressId": "0011442239",
    "streetName": "solitudestr.",
    "streetNrFirstSuffix": null,
    "streetNrFirst": null,
    "streetNrLastSuffix": null,
    "streetNrLast": null,
    "houseNumber": "25",
    "houseName": null,
    "city": "stuttgart",
    "postcode": "70499",
    "stateOrProvince": null,
    "countryName": null,
    "poBoxNr": null,
    "poBoxType": null,
    "attention": null,
    "geographicAreas": [
      
    ],
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "title": null,
    "region": "BW",
    "additionalInfo": null,
    "properties": [
      
    ],
    "extAddressId": null,
    "entrance": null,
    "district": null,
    "addressLine1": null,
    "addressLine2": null,
    "addressLine3": null,
    "addressLine4": null,
    "companyName": null,
    "contactName": null,
    "houseNrExt": null,
    "derbyStack": false
  },
  {
    "footprint": null,
    "type": null,
    "addressId": "0011442246",
    "streetName": "solitudestr.",
    "streetNrFirstSuffix": null,
    "streetNrFirst": null,
    "streetNrLastSuffix": null,
    "streetNrLast": null,
    "houseNumber": "26",
    "houseName": null,
    "city": "stuttgart",
    "postcode": "70499",
    "stateOrProvince": null,
    "countryName": null,
    "poBoxNr": null,
    "poBoxType": null,
    "attention": null,
    "geographicAreas": [
      
    ],
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "title": null,
    "region": "BW",
    "additionalInfo": null,
    "properties": [
      
    ],
    "extAddressId": null,
    "entrance": null,
    "district": null,
    "addressLine1": null,
    "addressLine2": null,
    "addressLine3": null,
    "addressLine4": null,
    "companyName": null,
    "contactName": null,
    "houseNrExt": null,
    "derbyStack": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is JSON so you should rather consider using [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) which allows execution of arbitrary JMESPath queries rather than trying to parse it using regular expressions.

In particular your case you can come up with the comma-separated list of these addresIds using the following expression:

```
[*].addressId | join(',',@)
```

Demo:

[image]

If you really need to surround these addressIds with quotation marks you will need to switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following Groovy code:

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(),'$..addressId').collect {it -> "\"$it\""} as String
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. sorry my mistake. but i need output as integers i.e [0011442239, 0011442246]. How to achieve this?